# RIDE Error : ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, robotframework

I started using RIDE Robot framework for testing RESTAPI calls. I am stuck with the first step, i.e 'Create Sesison'. The error that I keep getting is 'ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack'.

The keyword that I am using is 'Create Session' from the RequestsLibrary(This is after importing the RequestsLibrary to my test suite). The parameters that I pass to the Create Session are 'alias','uri' and 'headers'. I did give a suitable name for the alias and the uri is correct. The problem seems to be with the headers. The format in which I am passing the headers is headers={'WSUsername':'xyz', 'WSPassword':'abc'}

I did try this in eclipse with the same RequestsLibrary and it is working fine. The selinium implementation for RIDE seems straight forward and I couldn't find any documents online for testing RESTAPI calls through RIDE.

I started using RIDE recently. So, will be grateful for any help received here. And any documents or links for testing RESTAPI calls would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Headers argument is expecting a dictionary and what you give is a string (default type of variable in Robot Framework).

What you should do, is built a dictionary with your headers and then give it to Create Session:

```
${headers} =  create dictionary  WSUsername  xyz  WSPassword  abc
Create Session  alias=xxx  uri=yyy  headers=${headers}
```